# Correlation between discrete and binary variables

Tags: correlation, categorical-data, binary-data, discrete-data

I have a binary variable representing happiness. This variable can take binary values of 0 (not happy) and 1 (happy).

I have another discrete variable representing valence (representing if emotion is positive or negative) and arousal (intensity of emotion). These variables can take integer values between 1 (negative emotion, not intense) and 9 (positive emotion, intense).

Now I would like to calculate the correlation between the binary variable and the discrete variable (valence). Which correlation measure can I use for this purpose?

Second, When I would like to calculate the correlation between the binary variable and both discrete variables (valence and arousal) what measure could I use?

Third and last, what correlation measure can be used to calculate the correlation between the two discrete variables (valence and arousal)?